# Magnitude of charge on each plate of a parallel capacitor? Why should I multiply by two?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, textbook-erratum

Here's the full question:

> A parallel-plate capacitor has a plate area of $0.2\ \mathrm m^2$ and a plate separation of $0.1\ \mathrm{mm}$. To obtain an electric field of $2.0\ 10^6\ \mathrm{V/m}$ between the plates, the magnitude of the charge on each plate should be:

Using the equations $C = \epsilon_0 A/d = q/V$, and $V=Ed$, I rearrange to: $q = \epsilon_0AV/d = \epsilon_0AE$

I get $3.5\  10^{-6}\ \mathrm C$, but the answer is twice that. Why is this the case? If the charge is $Q$, each plate will have either $Q$ or $-Q$, so that's not it. I think it has to do with some assumption within the equation relating the electric field to the voltage and plate separation ($V=Ed$). I notice this comes from the equations $V=(kq)/d$ and $E=(kq)/d^2$, which (I think) are for point charges but can also apply to parallel plates. But I'm not sure how this tells me why my answer is the answer/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks to me like the answer you have been given is incorrect.

The way I see it you have a C of approximately $18 nF$

The electric field is the voltage divided by the gap - so the voltage across the capacitor is $200 V$.

Now you can use $Q=CV$ to get $Q=3.6\mu C$ (actually $3.5$ probably I just did an approximate calculation to check your working)

Comment: I think you're right--I went back and double checked the answer against a few of the other questions on this assignment and it seems that 3.5μC is actually correct.